# Is this a valid proof for a surjective transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

**Given**

$\mathbb{F}$ is a field. Let $f\colon M_{22}(\mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}$ be a transformation defined by $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \to a + d$ for all $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \in M_{22}(\mathbb{F})$

**Amateur tries to proof**

Let $\begin{pmatrix}a & 0\\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \in M_{22}(\mathbb{F}) \Rightarrow a \in \mathbb F \Rightarrow \forall a \in \mathbb F: a + 0 = a  \Box$

In my mind, this proves that every element of $\mathbb F$ is hit by the function, but I'm not sure. Please help me and show me how to correct it or how to do it better :) Thank you!

Comment: Strange implications but of course your function is surjective by that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter way to prove surjectivity with your map (which is the *trace* map) is this:

The trace map is a linear map from $M_{22}(\mathbf F) \to\mathbf F$. As $\mathbf F$ is a one-dimensional space over itself, a linear map to $\mathbf F$ is either $0$ or onto. Clearly, it is not $0$, so it is onto.